# how can i display uint8 values on a oled display

Tags: avr, display

I can compile the code but nothing shows

```
int main(void){
    lcd_init(LCD_DISP_ON);
    lcd_clrscr();
    lcd_set_contrast(0x00);
    lcd_gotoxy(0,3);
    lcd_puts((char*)&temperature);
    lcd_gotoxy(1,2);
    lcd_puts((char*)&humidity); 
    lcd_puts("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: probably you use a wrong driver, or may be `lcd_set_contrast(0x00);` is an issue (try values greater than zero)

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming problems; are you sure this is a programming problem?  Were you ever able to get any text to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the numerical data (e.g. `uint8_t`) to a *string* before you can display it.

E.g., the `uint8_t` value `123` is one byte, but to display it, it must be converted to a three-character/-byte string `1`, `2`, `3`, i.e. the three `char`s 0x31, 0x32, 0x33.

For that, you can use the function [`itoa()`](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1gaa571de9e773dde59b0550a5ca4bd2f00.html) ("integer to ascii") to copy the integer value to a `char` array you provide. Note that the `char` array must be big enough to hold any possible number-string, i.e. if your values are `uint8_t`'s (range 0...255) the array must be at least three characters long.

To have a character array handled as a string in C(-libraries), you need an additional `char` to hold the string terminator `'\0'`.

Example:

```
char tempStr[3+1]; // One extra for terminator

// Clear tempStr and make sure there's always a string-terminating `\0` at the end
for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(tempStr); i++ ) {
  tempStr[i] = '\0';
}

itoa(temperature, tempStr, 10);

// Now we have the string representation of temperature in tempStr, followed by at least one '\0' to make it a valid string.
// For example:
//      1 --> [ '1', '\0', '\0', '\0' ]
//    255 --> [ '2', '5', '5', '\0' ]
```